# Validate date of birth and and check age

Tags: php, date, datetime

In my form I am using drop down for showing day, month, year. Can you help me validate the date. I have to validate the entered age is greater than 15. Also check for leap year etc.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 6):

The PHP function [`checkdate`](https://www.php.net/checkdate) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkdate()
```

Age is not too hard too:

```
$validdate = (date("Y")-15).date("-m-d");
$bday = "$y-$m-$d";
if ($bday > $validdate) echo "underage!";
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first convert your input date in yyyy-mm-dd frormate.you can not directly put validatation. you have to convert your date into timestamp and then after you have to check validation.

```
$strSystemMaxDate = (date('Y') - 15).'/'.date('m/d');
if(strtotime($strDateOfBirth) > strtotime($strSystemMaxDate))
{
    $arrErrors[] = _("Minimum age is 15 years.");
    $blnValidated = false;
}
```

Comment: why to use timestamp to compare? strings can be compared as well