# date validation for year, month, day. how is it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date validation in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910245/date-validation-in-php)

date validation for year, month, day each separate.
if date typed in input less of date now (date submit) return false.
hoe are them??

```
$data_go = '1390/04/28';
$ddmmyyy='([1-9][\d]{3})[- \/.]([0-1][\d])[- \/.]([0-3][\d])';
            if(preg_match("/$ddmmyyy$/", $data_go)) {
               return TRUE;
            }else {
              return FALSE;
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+validation+php

Comment: You're missing a `0` from the year part of the regex (should be `[0-9]`, not `[1-9]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the optional `$matches` argument from [`preg_match`](http://us.php.net/preg_match) to capture the different regex groups you've specified, and then determine individually whether each of them is greater than or equal to today's date. You can use the various arguments in the [`date`](http://us.php.net/date) function to return the month, day of month, and year, respectively.